# Changing session variable after views are rendered Django

Tags: python, django

I have two session variables that are required to be altered after rendering.When I try the following-

```
def my_view(request) 
    rend= render(request,"chat_page.html",{"answer":questions[request.session["stage"]]["instruction"]})
    request.session["stage"]=request.session["stage"]+1

    return rend
```

I observe that first `stage`variable is modified and then rendering is done.Is there a way that I can change value of `stage` after rendering is done.

Comment: after rendering did you mean you want stage to be modified only after rendering the template ? That is not possible I think. But why do you want to modify it only after rendering ?

Comment: It is a basic chatbot app where stage is basically the question number on which rendering has to be done.Once rendering is done the reply again calls the same page with stage=stage+1 that is the next question and so that has to be rendered now.

Comment: Then it should work i think. You are incrementing after each answer is passed to context.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to create an HttpResponse manually and insert the rendered string since the `render` method returns an iterator which isn't evaluated until the last moment.

```
content = render_to_string("chat_page.html",{"answer":questions[request.session["stage"]]["instruction"]})
response = HttpResponse(content)
request.session["stage"] = request.session["stage"] + 1
return response
```

Comment: It does not work.Still the value passed to request.session["stage"] in content is one greater than it should be.

Comment: Sorry, the order of the above code was wrong. You'll need to create the response before changing the session. I updated the answer.